# Is it possible to make water steam batteries?

Tags: thermodynamics, electricity, temperature, physical-chemistry, batteries

I have a few questions,

What happens if we compress water steam?

Does its temperature increase (Gay-Lussac’s law)?
Or does it become liquid?

Can we store the compressed water steam in a tank and use it later on, when we require to generate electricity.

Comment: There were railroad steam engines that did not have a firebox (for safety reasons because of where they operated). They filled up from a central steam plant and then went about their business using the stored superheated water/steam.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fireless_locomotive

Comment: But note! Those "fireless" steam engines stored _liquid_ water at high temperature and pressure. They did not store steam as compressed gas. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fireless_locomotive#Steam

Comment: @SolomonSlow - absolutely correct, but that is true of real steam engines as well - the boiler pressure is high enough to keep most of the water as liquid well above 100C, with steam available above the water line. As steam is used, more comes out of the liquid and the temperature of the 'bottle' slowly drops until they need to go fill up again. (One could argue that the water is highly compressed steam, but that is semantics).

Comment: From the phase diagram steam becomes water for high enough pressure? https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Phase-diagram-of-water_fig1_291075075

Comment: Why would you use compressed steam rather than compressed air,  as in most power tools?

Comment: @nasu According to the "Fireless Locomotive" article cited above, the reason for choosing steam vs. compressed air was somewhat determined by the availability of one or the other. One of the applications was a "shunt engine" that moved coal cars in and out of a coal-fired power plant. Steam power would be a natural choice for that. On the other hand, if there was a factory somewhere that had a lot of pneumatically powered machinery, then a pneumatically powered locomotive might be a better choice for that location.

Comment: For that time it makes sense.  But the OP is asking for now, when compressed gas tubes are easily available. And compressors for air too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can store pressurized steam just like you can store pressurized air or pressurized CO2, and use the pressure to power something later.

The trick is that air or CO2 will remain a gas at room temperature but steam obviously condenses and loses pressure as it cools, so you need a really well insulated tank to prevent heat loss.

Steam will become liquid under enough pressure because the water phase transition between liquid and gas depends on temperature and pressure. Assuming that you're keeping the heat in somehow, then that pressurized water will turn back to steam when you relieve the pressure past the phase transition point again, and that will re-pressurize the tank because steam takes up more volume than water. So it's a great pressure battery if you can build it.